# ajax call not showing $_GET variables

Tags: zend-framework2

i am sending 2 parameters with-in ajax call from `zf2`. I am getting them in `print_r()` function. for e.g

```
**echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
exit();**
```

but when i want to use them in variables like this:

```
**$sid = $_GET('sid');
$rowid = $_GET('rowid');**
```

It gives error in broswer console.

****Fatal error**:  Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square bracket to access arrays in PHP:

```
$sid = $_GET['sid'];
$rowid = $_GET['rowid'];
```